# How to use wait() and notifyAll() to communicate between a GUI class and logic thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I have 3 primary classes in my program. The first extends applet (and acts as my main), the second is a thread (implementing Runnable) that handles the back-end logistics / communication with the server, and the third is a JPanel class, which creates the GUI (this is created in a new thread by way of a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` in the main (applet) class.

The GUI class communicates with the back-end thread several times to get data to display on the screen. My problem is that the GUI is displaying its components before the back-end class supplies them with data. So, I want to tell the GUI to call a method in the other thread, wait to hear back from it, and then display its components. I've tried several variations of:

```
Object[] data = backend.Method1(); 
wait();
showComponents(data);
```

on the GUI class, and placing `notifyAll();` at the bottom of Method1 in the back-end thread, but I get a warning in netbeans (Invoking Object.wait outside of a synchronized context), and the program crashes on a `java.lang.illegalmonitorstateexception` when it runs. I've tried adding the `synchronized` keyword to the two methods, but this causes the program to freeze.

I'm (obviously, I'm sure) just learning about multi-threading: What am I misunderstanding here?

I have a feeling that its relevant that the JPanel class does not implement runnable.

EDIT: As per @MadProgrammer's suggestion, I'm utililzing a SwingWorker and it seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for pointing me to it, I had never heard of them before.

```
 final JLabel loading = new JLabel("loading");
    loading.setVisible(true);
    add(loading);

    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker<Map<String, ArrayList<Time[]>>, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, ArrayList<Time[]>> doInBackground(){
            System.out.println("doing");
            Map<String, ArrayList<Time[]>> toReturn = dbh.getTimes(specToPass);
            return toReturn;
        }

        public void done(){
            try {
                loading.setVisible(false);
                Map<String, ArrayList<Time[]>> weekMap = new HashMap(this.get());
                showTimes(weekMap);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    };
    sw.execute();
```

I hope you'll let me know if I'm not implementing this properly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DON'T.  Blocking the UI in any way is ALWAYS a bad idea.  This will make your application "hang" and prevent the UI from been updated (or responding to any input from the user).

This makes a very bad user experience.

Instead, use some kind of call back that allows the data thread to send updates back to the UI as is required.  This should allow you UI to display something like a "wait" message while it waits for data from the data thread.

You could also use a `SwingWorker` to handle the data collection, but it might be to simple for your over all needs, but it provides simple methods for synchronizing any updates back to the UI.

Make sure that all creation/modification/interaction with the UI is done within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

**Updated**

The basic work flow (IMHO) should look something like...

- UI - request data from background thread, pass a listener interface
  to the background thread (with methods like `loadingDone` and
  `loadingFailed` for exmaple
- UI - Display "loading" message.  May display a nice animated GIF
- Thread - When data is loaded (assuming it all went well), package the data and passing it back via the `loadingDone` method
- UI - When `loadingDone` is called, re-sync with the EDT (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`) and update the UI.

This would actually be simpler with a `SwingWorker` and it would provide progress updates built in

Comment: What if I broke the method in the GUI into two - one that calls the method on the background thread and displays the loading window. Then, at the bottom of the method in the background thread, have it call a second method on the GUI thread, which hides the loading window and displays the components? This seems like it would work, but I'm afraid its a little ugly?

Comment: Your UI should call the background thread to get the data, passing it reference to something like an interface that has a couple of methods like `loadingDone` and `loadingFailed`.  You should then display a "wait" message on the UI, maybe use a nice animated GIF or something.  When `loadingDone` (or `Failed`) is called.  You MUST resync the call back to the EDT (using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and then push the data to the UI.  Personally, I would pass the data back via the `loadingData` method